# Iteration through a list derived using set is not as expected in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to first identify some unique values in a list of values and then reconstruct the original list from the unique values. For example lets say in a directory I have following data sets

```
a_test_1.txt  a_test_2.txt  a_test_3.txt  b_test_1.txt  b_test_2.txt  b_test_3.txt
```

I would like to uniquely identify a_ and b_ . I think I succeed in this. Following this I would like to use this list which contains a_ and b_ and go back to the original list of files. Here is the code I used

### **Attempt 1**

```
import os, fnmatch
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result


ids_train=[]
#base='/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/'
base = 'attempt/'
for path in find('*.txt',base):
        ids_train.append(path)
ids2=[]
for idd in ids_train:
        ids2.append(idd.split('test')[0])
ids2=list(set(ids2))
# I will do some operations on ids2 here which I am skipping for simplicity
for idd in ids2:
        print(idd)
print("now printing resconstructed")
for idd in ids2:
        for data in find(idd.strip(base)+'*',base):
                print(data,idd.strip(base)+'*')
```

### Output

```
attempt/a_
attempt/b_
now printing resconstructed
attempt/b_test_1.txt b_*
attempt/b_test_2.txt b_*
attempt/b_test_3.txt b_*
```

### Attempt 2

Now I tried absolute path instead of relative

```
import os, fnmatch
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result


ids_train=[]
base='/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/'
#base = 'attempt/'
for path in find('*.txt',base):
        ids_train.append(path)
ids2=[]
for idd in ids_train:
        ids2.append(idd.split('test')[0])
ids2=list(set(ids2))
# I will do some operations on ids2 here which I am skipping for simplicity
for idd in ids2:
        print(idd)
print("now printing resconstructed")
for idd in ids2:
        for data in find(idd.strip(base)+'*',base):
                print(data,idd.strip(base)+'*')
```

### Output

```
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/a_
now printing resconstructed
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_test_1.txt b*
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_test_2.txt b*
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_test_3.txt b*
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/a_test_3.txt *
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_test_1.txt *
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/a_test_2.txt *
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_test_2.txt *
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/b_test_3.txt *
/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/a_test_1.txt *
```

In both cases I failed to reconstruct the desired list

Comment: What's the "desired list"?

Comment: The format from either attempt 1 or attempt 2 will do as long as it has all the files from the original list.

Comment: However, it should be created using the unique list as I will delete some of the values later but not doing that right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strip command is misinterpreted as strip removes the indvidual characters from the beginning and ending of the string. What was needed was replace. This code worked correctly

```
import os, fnmatch
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result


ids_train=[]
#base='/data/data_us4/home/plaquestudy/nhm_processing/plaque_CNNSeg/attempt/'
base = 'attempt/'
for path in find('*.txt',base):
        ids_train.append(path)
ids2=[]
for idd in ids_train:
        ids2.append(idd.split('test')[0])
ids2=list(set(ids2))
# I will do some operations on ids2 here which I am skipping for simplicity
for idd in ids2:
        print(idd)
print("now printing resconstructed")
for idd in ids2:
        for data in find(idd.replace(base,'')+'*',base):
                print(data,idd.replace(base,'')+'*')
```

### Output

```
attempt/a_
attempt/b_
now printing resconstructed
attempt/a_test_3.txt a_*
attempt/a_test_2.txt a_*
attempt/a_test_1.txt a_*
attempt/b_test_1.txt b_*
attempt/b_test_2.txt b_*
attempt/b_test_3.txt b_*
```